# Cling Kernel for Jupyter on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, jupyter, cling

I built Cling on my laptop with Ubuntu 15.04 following the instructions given on https://github.com/root-mirror/cling#jupyter because I wanted to use the Cling kernel for Jupyter. I installed Jupyter, I checked that Cling is in my PATH, but when I type the command

```
jupyter kernelspec install cling
```

I get the following

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cling'
```

Someone knows what's happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the source code](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_client/blob/master/jupyter_client/kernelspecapp.py#L73),
`jupyter kernelspec install` command expects the path to the directory containing kernel spec file (kernel.json) as an argument. So if
you cloned the cling repository in, say, ~/cling/src, this should work:

```
jupyter kernelspec install ~/cling/src/tools/cling/tools/Jupyter/kernel/cling
```

Comment: Oh, and you'll also need to install clingkernel python package by `pip install ~/cling/src/tools/cling/tools/Jupyter/kernel`.

Comment: Thank you @user5266681, this command was missing! It looks to have worked fine, I see the c++ kernel in the list of available kernels on Jupyter, but when I open a notebook the kernel dies.

Comment: Cling kernel uses python3. So I think you need to `apt-get install python3-pip` and reinstall the kernel by `pip uninstall clingkernel` followed by `pip3 install`.

Answer (score 3):

That's probably because in your folder 3 versions of Cling kernel are defined (C++11, C++14 and C++17).
So instead of trying to add Cling try to add one of those versions or all three if you want to.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just one minute ago, but I was able to solve it. I  executed:

```
$ jupyter kernelspec install --user cling-cpp11
```

directly from `/home/ubuntu_user/cling_ubuntu/share/cling/Jupyter/kernel`.

The installation was successful, I moved to my working directory and called a jupyter notebook; it opened ok, but the kernel immediately died.

I thought the problem was that I have to install cling from where I was going to call the jupyter notebook, and I did so:

After uninstalling the kernel (also from `/home/ubuntu_user/cling_ubuntu/share/cling/Jupyter/kernel`) with:

```
jupyter kernelspec uninstall cling-cpp11
```

I repeated all the installation process:

Let's assume that you are usually going to call jupiter from `/home/ubuntu_user`, and you have your cling repository here

```
/home/ubuntu_user/cling_ubuntu.
```

Then:

1. Go there: `$ cd /home/ubuntu_user`
2. `$ source activate my_env` (I work with Anaconda, so I activated my environment)
3. `$ export PATH=/home/ubuntu_user/cling_ubuntu/bin:$PATH`
4. `$ cd cling_ubuntu/share/cling/Jupyter/kernel/cling-cpp11`
5. `$ pip install -e.`
6. Here you have to move to your future working directory.

   `$ cd /home/ubuntu_user`, type:

   `$ jupyter kernelspec install --user cling_ubuntu/share/cling/Jupyter/kernel/cling-cpp11`

   .. and the kernel is still alive and works ok.